# How can I attribute how much sales volume came from each medium in a log-log market mix model?

Tags: mixed-model, optimization, interpretation, nonlinear-regression, marketing

So I started off with this regression equation:
$$
sales = \beta_{d}*{(ds_{t} + (ar_{d} * ds_{t-1})})^a_{d} + \beta_{tv}*{(tv_{t} + (ar_{tv} * tv_{t-1})})^a_{tv} + \beta_0
$$
Where $ds$ is the amount of money spend on digital marketing, and $ds_{t-1}$ is the money spend the previous month. $\beta_{d}$ is the regression coefficient, $ar_{d}$ is the carry over rate of and $a_{d}$ determines the saturation point for the medium.

I have then log transformed both sides to get this equation:
$$
ln(sales) = \beta_{d}*{ln(ds_{t}) + (ar_{d} * ln(ds_{t-1}))})^a_{d} + \beta_{tv}*({ln(tv_{t}) + (ar_{tv} * ln(tv_{t-1}))})^a_{tv} + \beta_0
$$

I'm using scipy.optimize.least_squares to run a bounded regression and get the optimal fit. I want to be able to interpret these variables, so,

1. In the log model how would I interpret the carryover rate and saturation point?
2. How will I interpret the entire digital marketing/tv term to get the sales contributed by that medium?

I would appreciate it if anyone who's worked on a media/market mix model can provide some insight into this or if you can let me know if I've made any errors.

Thanks